# NOT IN AND IN condition mysql

Tags: mysql

I have SQL query design as below.

```
SELECT (THIS ITEMS) 
FROM (TABLES) 
WHERE(SOME CONDITION) AND NOT IN (CONDITION) AND IN (CONDITION)
```

But not getting proper output as required, as 'IN' condition isn't wrking properly

Comment: Post your complete SQL query

Comment: Have you `NULL` values in your `CONDITION`?

Comment: Hi Varinder, Wanted to know whether can i use some other operator instead of 'IN'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a column to compare to. Proper syntax is (note the `column_expression`):

```
SELECT <select_list>
FROM <table_expression>
WHERE <column_expression> [NOT] IN (<comparison_list>)
```

For example,

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tab
WHERE col3 IN ('yes', 'no')
AND col4 NOT IN ('no', 'maybe')
```

---

Note you can also use a single-column result set instead of a static comparison list, as in:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tab
WHERE col3 IN (SELECT filterValues FROM table2)
```

**but** it is much more optimal to use an `EXISTS` clause for this case:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tab
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE filterValues = col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need brackets around certain conditions.

```
Example 1:
Select all persons who are active and have an invoice 
Person->Invoice (1 to Many)
SELECT * FROM person WHERE active=1 AND person_id IN (SELECT person_id FROM invoice)

Example 2:
Select all person who are active, do not have a cat, and have an invoice

SELECT * FROM person WHERE active=1 AND person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM people_with_cats) AND person_id IN  (SELECT person_id FROM invoice)
```